# Sendgrid emails being sent without the template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid, actionmailer

My sendgrid emails are being sent ok, but the template is never loaded. I have tried multiple times with many templates but they are never called, so there must be something wrong with my call.

This is the call from the controller:

```
AdminMailer.with( email: "xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com" , id:item.id, name: item.name, room: item.room.name).send_stock.deliver_later
```

This is my admin_mailer.rb

```
class AdminMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def send_stock
    mail(to: params[:email],
      subject: 'Foto sin inventario',
      body: 'email body',
      delivery_method_options: {
        api_key: ENV["SENDGRID_API"]
      },
      template_id: 'd-2d99d960ed47490497f1a99af32cd706', 
      dynamic_template_data:{
        'id': params[:id],
        'name': params[:name],
        'room': params[:room]
      }
    )
  end
```

and this is the output from rails:

```
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [d8927648-36ca-4e60-afd3-7fe6ea1b936f] Performing ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob (Job ID: d8927648-36ca-4e60-afd3-7fe6ea1b936f) from Async(mailers) enqueued at 2022-09-29T22:08:22Z with arguments: "AdminMailer", "send_stock", "deliver_now", {:params=>{:email=>"xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com", :id=>4, :name=>"foto 3 exclusive", :room=>"Sala 1"}, :args=>[]}
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [d8927648-36ca-4e60-afd3-7fe6ea1b936f] AdminMailer#send_stock: processed outbound mail in 1.0ms
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [d8927648-36ca-4e60-afd3-7fe6ea1b936f] Delivered mail 6336175785e4_366932af97af0d39c27826@miguel.mail (7142.5ms)
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [d8927648-36ca-4e60-afd3-7fe6ea1b936f] Date: Thu, 29 Sep 2022 17:08:23 -0500
From: xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
To: xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
Message-ID: <6336175785e4_366932af97af0d39c27826@miguel.mail>
Subject: Foto sin inventario
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
template-id: d-2d99d960ed47490497f1a99af32cd706
dynamic-template-data: {:id=>4, :name=>"foto 3 exclusive", :room=>"Sala 1"}

email body
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [d8927648-36ca-4e60-afd3-7fe6ea1b936f] Performed ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob (Job ID: d8927648-36ca-4e60-afd3-7fe6ea1b936f) from Async(mailers) in 7150.18ms
```

Cant find a lot of documentation regarding issues with templates.

Comment: any input, please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you supply this function call with the body property, which tells the SDK you want to send an email with this body. You need to omit this property if you want to use a template.

At least, that's how it works in the node.js SDK, and according to this [sample code](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-ruby/blob/main/use-cases/transactional-templates.md#without-mail-helper-class), I assume Ruby works similarly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this gem https://github.com/eddiezane/sendgrid-actionmailer

Add to your gemfile:

```
gem 'sendgrid-actionmailer'
```

Then run `bundle`.

Then add the following in `application.rb`

```rb
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendgrid_actionmailer
config.action_mailer.sendgrid_actionmailer_settings = {
  api_key: ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY'],
  raise_delivery_errors: true
}
```

This is what your mailer will look like:

```rb
class AdminMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def send_stock
    mail(to: params[:email],
    body: '',
    subject: 'Foto sin inventario',
    template_id: 'd-2d99d960ed47490497f1a99af32cd706',
    dynamic_template_data: {
      'id': params[:id],
      'name': params[:name],
      'room': params[:room]
    })
  end
```

You'll invoke it with the usual ActiveMailer API:

```rb
AdminMailer.send_stock.deliver_later # or deliver_now
```

Hope it helps!